# How do I add a $ prefix to the tooltip in chart.js and have no decimal places

Tags: chart.js

I have a bar chart made in chart.js which pulls data from google.

The tooltips are fine, but I'd like to add a prefix $ before and show no decimal places.

https://codepen.io/jameswill77/pen/WNzXxeJ

```
  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var columns = data.getNumberOfColumns();
    var rows = data.getNumberOfRows();
    console.log(data.toJSON());

    const colors = ['#eeeeee', '#23F0C7'];
    dataj = JSON.parse(data.toJSON());
    console.log(dataj.cols[0].label);
    const labels = [];
    for (c = 1; c < dataj.cols.length; c++) {
      if (dataj.cols[c].label != "") {
        labels.push(dataj.cols[c].label);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ca be done by defining `options.plugins.tooltip.callbacks.label` function inside  your `setup` variable as follows.

```
var setup = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chartdata,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: dataj.cols[0].label
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {              
          label: ctx => ctx.label + ': $' + parseInt(ctx.parsed.y).toLocaleString()
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
  }
}
```

> Please take a look at the [Tooltip Callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) page from the Chart.js documentation for further details.